# lower each array-element of an array by a given value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to substract a fixed value from each array multiple objects. In this example you can see some coordinates as an array. Now the first value should be substracted by 10 and the second value by 20.

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;

var data = {
    "imagePoints": [{
        "id": "BTLS5YAJHbA5QWqRP",
        "coordinates": [ 534, 242 ],
        "content": "something"
    }, {
        "id": "yXCFyWaZMbpi8EczY",
        "coordinates": [ 398, 176 ],
        "content": "anything"
    }, {
        "id": "qJz9oMNfc8BmhMmEg",
        "coordinates": [ 272, 230 ]
    }]
}
```

The result would be for the first point `[524,222]`. How do I do that, as I have problems to get the values back in the data-variable:

```
data.forEach(function(point) {
    point.coordinates[0] - x;
    point.coordinates[1] - y;
}
```

Comment: `data.imagePoints.forEach(function(point) {
  point.coordinates[0] -= x; // and so on
}`

Comment: @raina77ow I like this solution much. Please post this as an answer. How can I prevent negative values? -10 should become 0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple: you only have to 1) follow the actual structure of your data source, and 2) reassign the value back:

```
data.imagePoints.forEach(function(point) { 
  point.coordinates[0] -= x;
  point.coordinates[1] -= y;
});
```

If you also want to account for limits, you'll have to use a simple assignment instead of compound one:

```
data.imagePoints.forEach(function(point) {
  point.coordinates[0] = Math.max(point.coordinates[0] - x, 0);
  point.coordinates[1] = Math.max(point.coordinates[1] - y, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented with map

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;

var arr = [x, y];

data.imagePoints.map(function (item) {
  item.coordinates = item.coordinates.map(function (coordinate, index) {
    return (coordinate - arr[index]) < 0 ? 0 : (coordinate - arr[index]);
  });
  return item;
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: What method should be used in this case? Map or forEach? Performance?

Comment: It's almost always an anti-pattern to use `.map` without assigning its result, so there's no point in first `.map`. The use of inner `.map` is also dubious: you change elements of an existing array, not create another array based on it.